# Inserting a value that relies on previous record's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have about 53 million rows in SQL Server2008 R2. I want to add a column called `Direction`. The value for direction relies on the previous rows's coordinates where a simple calculation is done to establish the change in coordinates per unique identifier.

How can I achieve this using an SQL script and/or statement?

Comment: it'll be nice if you make your question clear and brief....

Answer (score 4):

What you really want to do is use the new `LAG` and `LEAD` functions, but as these are only available in SQL Server 2012, you'll need to find another way.

There is a blog post here that discusses five ways to simulate `LAG` and `LEAD`: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

Answer (score 1):

This requires a self-join on the table, as I'm sure you've already figured out. If your unique identifier is not sequential, then you'll have to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to create a sequential row number, otherwise you can use the unique identifier.

This is my test table, just to give you the context...

```
CREATE TABLE #test(
    test_key INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    lat float,
    lon float,
    direction float
)
```

If the primary key is not sequential, you need to user `ROW_NUMBER`. Here is an example of this scenario. I've assumed that you're trying to get the direction in terms of degrees bearing clockwise off North. `ATN2` will return bearing bearing counter-clockwise off East, so I've swapped the X and Y coordinates to move the basis to North, and negated the result to correct the direction. This should give you a pretty good head start. Note, though, the in this example `lon`, `lat` and the resulting `direction` are all in radians. You'll probably need to convert these to degrees, as I've done in the second example.

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY test_key) AS seq, test_key, lat, lon, direction FROM #test)
UPDATE t SET direction = -ATN2(c2.lon-c1.lon, c2.lat-c1.lat)
FROM #test t, cte c1, cte c2 
WHERE t.test_key = c1.test_key
AND c2.seq = c1.seq + 1
```

The second example assumes a sequential primary key, and direction, lat and lon in degrees.

```
UPDATE t1 SET direction = -ATN2((t2.lon-t1.lon)*pi()/180.0, (t2.lat-t1.lat)*pi()/180.0)*180.0/pi()
FROM #test t1, #test t2
WHERE t2.seq = t1.seq + 1
```